# Why getaddrinfo( ) always cause segmentation fault?

Tags: c, networking, segmentation-fault, getaddrinfo, getnameinfo

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(){
    char buff[50];
    char port[5];

    printf("Enter address to lookup: ");
    fgets(buff, 50, stdin);

    printf("Enter Port: ");
    fgets(port, 5, stdin);

    struct addrinfo* res;
    struct addrinfo hints; memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints)); hints.ai_flags= AI_PASSIVE;

    __auto_type error = getaddrinfo(buff, port, &hints, &res);
    if (error < 0 )
        return 4;

    printf("Host IP: %s", buff);
    error = getnameinfo(res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen, buff, 50, 0, 0, 0);
    if (error < 0)
        return 5;

    printf("Host IP: %s", buff);
    freeaddrinfo(res);
}
```

Running This code Cause getaddrinfo( ) to terminate program due to a segmentation fault.
Edit: The error seems to come from getaddrinfo( ) after checking return Value of `getaddrinfo` the input is just
[www.google.com](http://www.google.com) (A bunch of other address have been tested also )
443 (tried it with port 80 as well )

Comment: What is your input? And for starters, add error checking code. Check return value of all functions - should not blindly dereference `res` without knowing whether it contains a valid pointer or not. Should not blindly assume `buff` contains a valid string without checking function return values.

Comment: @kaylum my input is just www.google.com with port 443 I know about error checking but this code is very simple that it's supposed to just work but something isn't right .

Comment: Your problem is you are passing `&res` to `getaddrinfo`. But, `res` is an _unitialized_ pointer. Try: `struct addrinfo res;` (i.e. _without_ the `*`). And, if you do that, change all `res->` into `res.`

Comment: @CraigEstey actually getaddinfo( ) is supposed to allocate the struct and assign the pointer to res According to the documentation

Comment: "it's supposed to just work". Well  it obviously isn't. Just add the error checking. All good code needs that and it will help you debug any problems that there may be. You can't just say "it should work" and not do basic debugging such as error checking, debug prints, running in debugger, etc.

Comment: @kaylum just edited the question with new code doing error checking always return with with number 4(i.e getaddrinfo seems to fail )

Comment: Don't return a random error code. Call `perror` or examine `errno` directly to get a more precise error reason.

Comment: @KhaledGaber Oops, my bad. But, I just found the real problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your original code, I get a `res` value of `0x1`.

The problem is that the `buff` and `port` strings have a newline (`\n`) in them.

When the newlines are stripped it runs to completion.

Here's the modified code I used:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>

void
fixup(char *buf)
{
    char *cp;

    cp = strchr(buf,'\n');
    if (cp != NULL)
        *cp = 0;
}

int
main()
{
    char buff[50];
    char port[5];

#if 1
    FILE *xf = stdin;
#else
    FILE *xf = fopen("input.txt","r");
#endif

    printf("Enter address to lookup: ");
    fgets(buff, 50, xf);
    fixup(buff);

    printf("Enter Port: ");
    fgets(port, 5, xf);
    fixup(port);

    struct addrinfo *res;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_flags = AI_ALL;

    getaddrinfo(buff, port, &hints, &res);
    printf("res=%p\n",res);
    printf("Host IP: %s\n", buff);

    getnameinfo(res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen, buff, 50, 0, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);
    printf("Host IP: %s\n", buff);

    freeaddrinfo(res);
}
```

Comment: so the whole problem was that getaddrinfo can't deal with a '\n' character, it's seems a little bit weird right :).

Comment: @KhaledGaber It could probably do a better job of protecting itself. But, `getaddrinfo` isn't "human facing" (i.e. it assumes its input has already been checked) for speed.